# Adding basemap in ArcMap gives blank window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am having issue while adding basemap to ArcMap 10.2. it was working OK earlier. Internet is strong. test connection says connected.
I have tried following
1: clearing display cache
2: reset internet explorer setting
3: tried to connect through catalogue servers but getting an error."we are unable to connect "

[image: Blank Window]

[image: Catalogue error]

Comment: HTTP support is rare in modern times. Using ancient software with modern data services is likely to fail eventually.

Answer (score 4):

You should keep an eye on the Esri blog, some base maps have been retired as discussed on the [blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-living-atlas/announcements/notification-that-old-esri-raster-basemaps-will-be-retired-esri_imagery_world_2d-and-esri_streetmap_world_2d/). They have also withdrawn [http](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/announcements/arcmap-users-support-for-http-raster-basemaps-ends-in-april-2022/) support which may be affecting you.

You are using an old unsupported version of ArcMap, time for you to upgrade or migrate to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I updated software to newer version and issue is resolved.